# Rewrite permuatation as disjoint cycles

Tags: permutations

Rewrite $(3412)(245) \in S_4$ as a product of distinct cycles.

I've only ever been given permutations as distinct cycles, transpositions or the matrix notation so I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite the cycles in the "matrix notation" as follows $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 2&3&4&1&5 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 1&4&3&5&2 \end{pmatrix}$

Then you apply the first permutation to the second (assuming composition order) i.e, reorder the first row of the second matrix to be the second row of the first. 
$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 5 \\ 4&3&5&1&2 \end{pmatrix}$

Giving the final permutation:
$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 4&3&5&1&2 \end{pmatrix}$
Can you read off the cycles?

Comment: (14)(235) are the cycles. Thanks!